# Accessing object property with backslashes

Tags: php

I'm having trouble accessing an object that has a property with backslashes. Tried the suggestions I could find so far, but to no avail. 
print_r of the object ($object) looks something like this

```
Cant\Access\This Object 
( 
    [properties:Cant\Access\This:private] => Array 
        ( 

            [firstName] => Rimas 

        ) 
)
```

The most commonly suggested option seems to be 
`$object->{'Cant\Access\This'}` but it just returns a NULL to me.

Comment: It says that the property is `private`, which means that it's only accessible from within the class itself.

Comment: Or with some `getter` function.

Comment: @u_mulder - Which would need to be within the class itself :-)

Comment: Problem is that this is an object i receive as a response from an API call as a result of retrieving data.

Comment: Sure, but as we don't know what object OP is using - we can't say anything.

Comment: Well, without knowing more than _"is an object receive as a response from an API"_ (which doesn't really tell us anything), we can't really help you. We have no idea what the flow is, what object that is, where or how it's populated. If it's a part of some SDK, then check the docs and see if there's any getter method for that property.

Comment: Hyperwallet SDK

Comment: Then I would recommend going through their documentation properly and check. If you can't find any getter method for that property, I would suggest asking the developers directly (you could always create an issue on their Github repo) or if they have some forum or similar.

Comment: Yes, I've already written an email to them about it. The thing is, this IS the getter method. To retrieve data, about a user, about an account, etc. And this is the format i receive it in.

Comment: _“The thing is, this IS the getter method”_ - and what exactly _is_ it, that it gets you?Probably instances of the according user/account/etc classes, I suppose? Well those in turn have getters, so you should probably call those, instead of trying to access properties directly. (Your example contains `firstName`, so my guess would be that actually you should be looking here, https://github.com/hyperwallet/php-sdk/blob/master/src/Hyperwallet/Model/User.php#L298)

Comment: @04FS This is embarrassing but that's exactly what it was. I don't know how I failed to notice that since I WAS using the object functions to set values.